# Similar answer situation, best thing to do?

Tags: discussion, answers

This situation occurred many times with me.

When two people answer a particular question in a very similar way, and it is in no way copied from one another since they are off by just a minute at the maximum, what is the best thing to do?

For example, I answered a question in a particular way and by the type I submitted, I see another answer solved in the same way, just a few seconds earlier. Do I delete my answer?

Comment: If it really does duplicate the answer of someone who posts before me, I delete my answer. If it adds anything additional, I leave it - but usually edit it to emphasize the new material.

Comment: If you delete your answer and the other deletes their answer for the same reason, then there are no answers left... I wouldn't worry too much about this is I were you.

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/about-posting-identical-answers-to-a-question) and also some of the posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8191).

Comment: @MartinSleziak That post, as far as I see, is about posting the answer 10 minutes later. My problem is more like posting seconds later, without knowledge of the previous post existing. It is nobody's mistake, but I just would like to know the right thing to do in such situations. Delete my answer or not.

Comment: @WinVineeth Did you look also at other posts I linked to? Basically you are saying that this question is closer to yours: [Courtesy/Etiquette: Writing an Almost-Identical Answer just After the Previous](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/courtesy-etiquette-writing-an-almost-identical-answer-just-after-the-previous)?

Answer (score -2):

I think that both of the posters should edit their answers to say that they did the same thing at (nearly) the same time.

I think the owner of the question should post a comment saying which answer is better (in their opinion).

If the answers are identical, make the earlier one the answer (because the second one might be copied-and-pasted).